# Typescript spread Parameters function calling issue

Tags: typescript

Is there a typesafe way of achieving this?

```
function foo(a: string) {
  return a;
}
function bar(b: number) {
  return b;
}

const fns = { foo, bar } as const;

function callThing<T extends keyof typeof fns>(name: T, ...params: Parameters<(typeof fns)[T]>): ReturnType<(typeof fns)[T]> {
  const result = fns[name](...params);
  // A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter.

  return result
  // Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<{ readonly foo: (a: string) => string; readonly bar: (b: number) => number; }[T]>'.
}

const fooResult = callThing("foo", "hello")
const barResult = callThing("bar", 42)
```

Comment: TS doesn't "understand" what `Parameters` and `ReturnType` do in the abstract. If you want to express this sort of thing the only way I know of is to use the refactoring described at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) so that you're using generic indexes into mapped types, as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w1GXGm). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I found to help here is to use function overloads:

```
function callThing<T extends keyof typeof fns, P extends Parameters<(typeof fns)[T]>>(
  name: T,
  ...params: P
): ReturnType<(typeof fns)[T]>;

function callThing(name: 'foo', ...params: Parameters<(typeof fns)['foo']>) {
  const result = fns[name](...params);

  return result;
}
```